# PHP include path problems on OSX

Tags: php, include, include-path

I'm working on Mac OSX Lion. This is a new computer and I'm working to set up my dev environment again.

When I try to include a nonsense, nonexistent file, the page loads fine.

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);

var_dump(include_once($dir . '/sg.php'));

// returns bool(false)
```

But when I try to include an actual, existent file, the page fails to load at all. Needless to say, all my includes are helplessly broken right now, throwing warnings left and right.

I've checked perms, ownership, and the `include_path` in `php.ini`. Now I'm just stuck and could use some help.

Comment: using MAMP or you've installed ordinary PHP/MySQL/Apache server?

Comment: What kind of warnings? What's the first warning you get?

Comment: I just turned display_errors On, so I'm now getting `No such file or directory in /Users/joshsmith/Sites/voterly/simplegeotest.php on line 4` instead of the HTTP 500 I was getting.

Comment: And just to make sure: You are certain that that file exists and the path is correct?

Comment: What happens when you change include_once to include()? The bool-false indicates that the include_once didn't load the requested file -- either b/c it's already loaded or it's not-found? What's the output of $dir?

Comment: openbasedir restriction?

Comment: The file does exist and the path is correct. There is no openbasedir restriction in my php.ini.

Comment: What is line 4 on simplegeotest.php?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is probably not improperly working include but wrong mysql socket file in php.ini.
Try to set it up to /tmp/mysql.sock.
I had mysql_connect in my included file and it reported partial error message "No such file or directory" on web page. When I tried to call index.php from commandline it appeared that it can't find mysql socket file - not the included file ;-)
-Maciej